# Why is Enum.Parse always resolving to default value?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, enums

For some reason Enum.Parse is resolving to the default value every single time. The following resolves to `Unknown`. Every single time. I'm doing this in the debugger's Watch window, and this is what I'm getting.

Enum definition, for reference:

```
[Flags]
public enum BugType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Beetle = 1 << 0,
    Spider = 1 << 1,
    Mosquito = 1 << 2,
    Any = Beetle | Spider
}
```

In the watch window and immediate window:

```
(BugType)Enum.Parse(typeof(BugType), BugType.Beetle.ToString(), true)
```

I can't understand why this is even happening in the Watch window, and the immediate window, and in the running debugging code. I can't get Enum.Parse to work.

For a little background, I noticed this happening and started testing because I discovered that JSON.NET was failing to deserialize these enums correctly. They were always coming back with the default value. So I started debugging, and I can't even get the most basic, simple, no-brainer example to work. I'm literally trying to Parse the string value I get from ToString'ing the enum itself!

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Your code returns Beetle for me.

Comment: Me also. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/IlMtJl Please give a [mcve]. Perhaps your real `enum` has duplicate values

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was just the debugging windows that was showing the wrong value, even though the value in the variable was correct. Probably the debugger was preventing showing the actual value to prevent side effects?

The reason I know it was just *showing* the wrong value is that when I stepped through the code, `if` statements testing the value, it was correct and went to the right if statement block for `Beetle` and not `Unknown`. Even though I was **literally looking at the variable** in the watch window and it showed `Unknown`!

Waste of time. VS was just showing me bogus values.